# Spring Boot React Google OAuth2 logout not redirecting

Tags: spring-boot, react-redux, axios, spring-security-oauth2

I am coding a Web Application the will allow users to login with a Google OAuth2 Account. I am using Node React for the front end and Spring Boot for the back end. So far I have the login functionality working. The logout function also seems to work somewhat, as I am able to see the expected response in the console log. The trouble I am have is that I expect to be redirected to http://localhost:8080/greeting after the logout button is clicked, however that is not happening. What am I doing wrong?

Header.js

```
class Header extends Component {
  renderContent(){
    switch (this.props.auth){
      case null:
        return;
      case false:
        return <li><a href="login/google">Login</a></li>
      default:
        return <li><button onClick={this.handleLogout} >Logout</button></li>
    }
  }
  ...
handleLogout = () => {
  axios({method: 'post',
         url: "http://localhost:8080/logout",
         withCredentials: true,
         headers: {'X-XSRF-TOKEN': cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')}
        })
  .catch(error => console.log('BAD', error))
  .then(reponse => console.log('GOOD', reponse));
        return response;            
    }
}
```

WebApp.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
      "/**",
                 "/login",
                "/greeting",
                "/error**",
                "/api/**").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
      .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
      .and()
    .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/greeting").permitAll()
            .and()
    .csrf()
      .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
      .and()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `handleLogout` function performs an AJAX request to the server - hence any redirect response will be handled by your callback function, not the browser - and the redirect will not happen.

You can do a sync. request to your server (not AJAX) or you can perform redirect yourself on the client side (using some JS code on your callbacks).

I would recommend the first option:

`<li><button onClick={this.handleLogout} >Logout</button></li>`

becomes:

`<li><a href="http://localhost:8080/logout" >Logout</a></li>`

---

**UPDATE 1:**
If you forced to perform the request using HTTP POST method then you can perform redirect in your "onSuccess" callback (**axios understands redirects and follows redirected link**):

```
handleLogout = () => {
  axios({method: 'post',
         url: "http://localhost:8080/logout",
         withCredentials: true,
         headers: {'X-XSRF-TOKEN': cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')}
        })
  .catch(error => console.log('BAD', error))
  .then(reponse => {
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/greeting";
  });
}
```

Comment: I am sending a POST to satisfy the use of the csrf protection on the server side. The documentation says it requires a POST with the X-XSRF-TOKEN in the header.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to come up with something very similar to what you have suggested here.

Answer (score 2):

The axios call won't redirect for you, you must handle this yourself on the frontend if the HTTP response code indicated a redirect

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. This is what I came up with, probably not the best code in world but its working for now. I'm thinking some sort of React Router or Redux implementation would be best practice, however I'm not currently familiar enough with them to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This is the solution I came up with, following jonash suggestion. I think it's a temporary fix until I learn React enough to refactor using best practice.

Updated Header.js

```
handleLogout = () => {
  axios({method: 'post',
         url: "http://localhost:8080/logout",
         withCredentials: true,
         headers: {'X-XSRF-TOKEN': cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')}
        })
  .catch(error => console.log('BAD', error))
  .then(response => { window.location = response.request.responseURL });
```